# How do I access using Python Dict and List

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here I am giving two variables namely "a", "result". If "result" matches with any of the record in "a" in "city" then it should return entire record of the "a" variable.

```
a = {
    "output": [
        {"name": "India",
        "state": [
            {
                "city": ["c", "d" ]
            }
        ],
        "city": [
            "g",
            "h"
        ]},
        {"name": "Telangana",
        "state": [
            {
                "city": ["a", "b" ]
            }
        ],
        "city": [
            "e",
            "f"
        ]}
        ]
    }
result = "e"
```

Expected results :

1)result="e"
then it should return   final output=

```
{"name": "Telangana",
            "state": [
                {
                    "city": ["a", "b" ]
                }
            ],
            "city": [
                "e",
                "f"
            ]}
```

for ex2:
2)result="d"
final output is

```
  {"name": "India",
            "state": [
                {
                    "city": ["c", "d" ]
                }
            ],
            "city": [
                "g",
                "h"
            ]}
```

Tried Code :

```
def filter(data,result):
    for item in a["output"]:
        for value in item.get('city',[]):
            if value==result:
                print(item)
            else:
                item.get('state',[])
                print(filter(item['state'],result))
filter(a,result)
```

Comment: The first step to fixing broken code is identifying how the code fails to meet expectations. Please [edit] your question to include this information. See [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't mentioned values not existing, so the easiest approach would be to do this:

```py
def filter_city(result):
    for item in a["output"]:
        if result in [*item["state"][0]["city"], *item["city"]]:
            return item
    return None

print(filter_city("e"))
print(filter_city("d"))
```

Output:

```py
{'name': 'Telangana', 'state': [{'city': ['a', 'b']}], 'city': ['e', 'f']}
{'name': 'India', 'state': [{'city': ['c', 'd']}], 'city': ['g', 'h']}
```

Comment: I like this answer as it is neat and tidy. Just be aware that it is fragile with respect to your data structure and if additional levels of nesting or key names changed this would not quote work without modification.

Comment: Note that you clobber `filter()` here something you might actually want to pass a version of your method into :-)

Comment: `return None` is unnecessary.

Comment: Right, `filter()` is a built-in. Should name it differently haha. Also, I like it to be more explicit, and I know that return is useless. I would imagine OP maybe wanting to return something different, so I added it just in case.

Answer (score 1):

First inside your function filter you're using the a variable instead of the parameter data.

Second you're checking if the current value is equal to the result, that's okey but what you do in the else statement you should move it outside the inner for loop and use a flag to check if you found the match or not.

```py
    def filter(data,result):
      for item in data["output"]:
        founded = False
        for value in item.get('city',[]):
          if value==result:
            print(item)
        if not founded:
          item.get('state',[])
          print(filter(item['state'], result))
```

I didn't test it but it should work! Feel free to test it and refactor it.